# Induction Method in a special case of $ n!+1 = m^2 $ (Brocard's Problem)

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, induction, alternative-proof

**Context:**
 [Brocard's problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brocard%27s_problem) is a problem in mathematics that asks to find integer values of $n$ and $m$ for which$$  n!+1 = m^2  \tag{1}$$ 
Let's define,
$$T=\left(\left\lfloor \frac{ (\lfloor\log(n) \rfloor -1)-1}{2}\right\rfloor +(n-2^{ \lfloor\log(n) \rfloor}+1) \times \lfloor\log(n) \rfloor \right)$$

Using elementary argument, it can be shown that,

> Brocard's problem has no solution when  $T$ is odd.

**Problem:**  I would like to prove it using ***induction method***.

**Question:**  How should I approach the problem?

It would be nice if someone post the proof. If that is not possible, leave a direction, please.

Comment: I don't get at what you are trying to prove. Are you trying to prove that Brocard's problem has no solution when $T$ is odd?